# MySQL JSON diff procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, json, edit-distance, stored-procedure

I'm building a procedure which compares two JSON objects and return two JSON objects with differences between each (compared keys and values).
But I have relatively superficial SQL knowledge, so I need your review to avoid any simple mistakes and improve my code.

**Compares "first" against "second" and returns the values in "first" that are not present in "second" OR has different value**

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS json_diff $$

# Compares "first" against "second" and
# returns the values in "first" that are not present in "second" OR has different value
CREATE PROCEDURE json_diff(IN first JSON, IN second JSON, INOUT firstResult JSON, INOUT secondResult JSON)
BEGIN
    DECLARE oldKey VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE oldVal, newVal INT;
    DECLARE i, secondHasKey INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE oldKeys, newKeys JSON;

    SELECT JSON_KEYS(first) INTO oldKeys;
    SELECT JSON_KEYS(second) INTO newKeys;

    WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(oldKeys) DO
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(oldKeys, CONCAT('$[',i,']')) INTO oldKey;
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(first, CONCAT('$.', oldKey)) INTO oldVal;

        SELECT JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(second, 'one', CONCAT('$.', oldKey)) INTO secondHasKey;

        IF secondHasKey = 1 THEN
            SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(second, CONCAT('$.', oldKey)) INTO newVal;
            IF oldVal != newVal THEN
                SELECT JSON_INSERT(firstResult, CONCAT('$.', oldKey), oldVal) INTO firstResult;
                SELECT JSON_INSERT(secondResult, CONCAT('$.',oldKey), newVal) INTO secondResult;
            end if;
        ELSE
            SELECT JSON_INSERT(firstResult, CONCAT('$.', oldKey), oldVal) INTO firstResult;
        end if;

        SET i = i + 1;
    end while;
END $$
```

**Use above PROCEDURE to make bidirectional comparison.**

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS json_diff_both $$

CREATE PROCEDURE json_diff_both(IN first JSON, IN second JSON, INOUT firstResult JSON, INOUT secondResult JSON)
BEGIN
    CALL json_diff(first, second, firstResult, secondResult);
    CALL json_diff(second, first, secondResult, firstResult);
END $$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a second part of the diff.

I've added the missing part, renamed the variables a bit to make it easier to work with, and added some comments.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS JSON_OBJECT_DIFF $$

CREATE PROCEDURE JSON_OBJECT_DIFF(IN a JSON, IN b JSON, INOUT aResult JSON, INOUT bResult JSON)
BEGIN
    DECLARE aKeys, bKeys JSON;
    DECLARE currentKey, currentKeyPath TEXT;
    DECLARE aVal, bVal JSON;
    DECLARE aKeysLength, bKeysLength, aHasKey, bHasKey INT;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT JSON_KEYS(a) INTO aKeys;
    SELECT JSON_KEYS(b) INTO bKeys;
    SELECT JSON_LENGTH(aKeys) INTO aKeysLength;
    SELECT JSON_LENGTH(bKeys) INTO bKeysLength;

    # Iterate keys in `a` as `currentKey`:
    # * If exists in `b` and !=, insert `a(currentKey)` and `b(currentKey)` into `aResult` and `bResult`
    # * If does not exist in `b`, insert `a(currentKey)` into `aResult`

    WHILE i < aKeysLength DO
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(aKeys, CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) INTO currentKey; /* Already quoted */
        SELECT CONCAT('$.', currentKey) INTO currentKeyPath;
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(a, currentKeyPath) INTO aVal;

        SELECT JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(b, 'one', currentKeyPath) INTO bHasKey;

        IF bHasKey = 1 THEN
            SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(b, currentKeyPath) INTO bVal;

            IF aVal != bVal THEN
                SELECT JSON_INSERT(aResult, currentKeyPath, aVal) INTO aResult;
                SELECT JSON_INSERT(bResult, currentKeyPath, bVal) INTO bResult;
            end if;
        ELSE
            SELECT JSON_INSERT(aResult, currentKeyPath, aVal) INTO aResult;
        END IF;

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    # Iterate keys in `b` as `currentKey`:
    # * If does not exist in `a`, insert `b(currentKey)` into `bResult`

    SET i = 0;
    WHILE i < bKeysLength DO
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(bKeys, CONCAT('$[', i, ']')) INTO currentKey; /* Already quoted */
        SELECT CONCAT('$.', currentKey) INTO currentKeyPath;

        SELECT JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(a, 'one', currentKeyPath) INTO aHasKey;

        IF aHasKey = 0 THEN
            SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(b, currentKeyPath) INTO bVal;
            SELECT JSON_INSERT(bResult, currentKeyPath, bVal) INTO bResult;
        END IF;

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
```

Comment: Keep in mind on code review, the code has to work as expected, so the second part of the diff wasn't necessary.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Got it, thanks :-)

Comment: When testing above code the string values are double quoted in the resulting objects. I think they should be unquoted before inserting into aResult / bResult: `SELECT JSON_INSERT(aResult, currentKeyPath, JSON_UNQUOTE(aVal)) INTO aResult; ... SELECT JSON_INSERT(bResult, currentKeyPath, JSON_UNQUOTE(bVal)) INTO bResult;` Or am I missing something here?